# How to point domain and subdomain to dedicated server using IP address?

Tags: dns, hosting, domain-name, web-hosting

I have dedicated server with 1and1 and domain name with godaddy.

To point my domain to my server i just pointed my dedicated server IP using "A" RECORD (at godaddy)  and didn't change anything like DNS etc.Main domain working fine but when i create sub domain i am getting error.

> The server at abc.yourdomain.com can't be found, because the DNS
>   lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's
>   name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by
>   having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It
>   can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall
>   preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

I know this might be very basic question for you experts but i have very minimal knowledge of domain and server configuration.I tried to google and try to find exact solution for the issue but can't manage to find.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Is this when you are creating the subdomain that you get the error?

Comment: i created subdomain in my server using plesk panel but when i try to open that sub domain in browser i am getting this error

Comment: I *think* Plesk will only configure that subdomain on the web server. It won't create it in DNS. You will have to add the zone on your DNS server, and give it an appropriate 'A' record pointing at your web server.

Comment: Hi Adam many many thanks to you.You pointed right keyword to me and i searched that on google and manage to ADD ZOne in DNS server.I would like to accept your reply as answer plz post it as seperate rather then comment.

Comment: Done! Thanks! I've tried to make it a bit of a better answer than the comment, in case it's useful for anyone else who finds this thread later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Plesk to add a subdomain, it configures your web server to accept requests for that subdomain.
You may still need to add this new subdomain in DNS, or else nothing else on the internet will be able to find this subdomain.
The method of doing this will depend on your hosting provider/DNS server software. Most hosting providers have a custom web interface which allows you to manage your DNS domains.
Godaddy have [instructions for managing subdomains](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4080/managing-a-domain-names-subdomains) in their DNS web interface.